# What is Fondant?

Tags: candy

I read about candies that have "fondant" in the middle used as filling - what is it?  Are there other uses for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of fondant: poured and rolled.

Poured fondant is sugar and water that has been cooked to the soft-ball stage and then beaten until creamy and opaque. If you've ever had a [Cadbury Creme Egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadbury_Creme_Egg), the filling is fondant.

Rolled fondant is the icing commonly used on wedding cakes. It is also used prominently in cake baking TV shows, such as [Ace of Cakes](http://www.foodnetwork.com/ace-of-cakes/index.html). It too is primarily sugar and water, but it also has gelatin, glycerin, and glucose to thicken the sugar but keep it pliable.

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fondant
- [Fondant recipe](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/rolled-fondant/Detail.aspx)

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of poured fondant, only rolled. Ya learn something new every day.