# Can the Cadbury Creme Egg's filling be bought independently?

Tags: candy

I want to buy the filling of Cadbury Creme Eggs to use it in another dessert. I remember that being available but I cannot come up with the keywords to search for it. Maybe something similar is sold by another company with another name?

Comment: Apparently someone thinks the question is too localized. Which would imply that they don't live in the western hemisphere where Cadbury Eggs proliferate this time of year.

Answer (score 13):

The keyword you are looking for is "fondant".

Fondant is a soft candy characterized by a smooth texture that comes from small sugar crystals.

It can be as simple as sugar and water boiled to the right temperature and allowed to cool undisturbed. Kind of like fudge without the fat and chocolate.

The filling of Cadbury Creme eggs is called "poured fondant" vs the more solid "rolled fondant" that is often used to decorate cakes.

There are [many](http://www.sprinklebakes.com/2011/07/poured-fondant-and-petit-fours.html) [recipes](http://www.wilton.com/recipe/Quick-Pour-Fondant-Icing-1) for fondant online and it can be [purchased](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KEUKVA) [premade](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I7C6GO).

See this question:
[What is Fondant?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7108/2001)

Comment: I'm curious, in the question you linked, Hobodave's answer mentioned beating the sugar water mixture into creaminess, while you said allowed the mixture to cool undisturbed. Is that just a different stage of making fondant? Let it cool undisturbed first, and then beat it?

Comment: @Jay- correct. Like fudge, to get small crystals you have to let it cool to 150F or so without any crystals and then beat it like mad so you get a ton of tiny crystals all at once.

Comment: Also the link you added to the purchased premade fondant is not actually premade. You have to add water, corn syrup and extract to it(says so in the description), which basically means its just powdered sugar. over $10 for 4lbs of powdered sugar doesn't sound like a very good deal lol

Comment: Good catch. I haven't tried actually using those products.

Comment: @Sobachatina - Fair comment on dropping the temp I just figured solution 1 was too simple for words, updated it. The glucose helps with the crystal BTW :)

Comment: Of course, Cadbury also uses invert sugar (glucose-fructose) which is super sweet and smooth and retains almost all of its moisture (has a honey-like texture). For this kind of thing, I prefer to buy the pre-made, fondant is dirt cheap and generally doesn't have a lot of extra ingredients. But if you're going pre-made, an even better choice is buttercream frosting (real or fake); it's creamier, less cloyingly sweet, very pliable, and you can use it right out of the container.

Answer (score 7):

**You can make your own in minutes:** (requires wooden spoon and bowl)

400g icing (confectioners) sugar
75ml water
150ml glucose
5 drops yellow food colouring (leave out for white!)

Mix the water and glucose until smooth, then add the icing sugar until you have the desired consistency, then add the food colouring, if you're making the yellow centre!

**You can go the pro route:** (requires sugar thermometer and standing mixer)

100ml water
100ml glucose
750g sugar (fine or normal grain)

Heat to sugar to soft ball stage (235-240F/113-116C)
Pour into a standing mixer and let the temp drop to 118F/48C 
Then mix until creamy.
Add flavouring or colouring after about 30sec of mixing.

***I know which I'd rather do with the kids at Easter!!!***